# Count the number of lines in a text file that contain a specific character (Linux)?

Tags: linux, count, grep, wc

I have a .csv (utf-8 text file). It has millions of lines. I can count the lines with `wc -l`. I want to count only lines with specific characters in them. So if 2M of 10M lines had a "1" in them, I'd like to return 2M.

Is this possible? Will this be horrendously slow? What are some ways to do this?

Comment: You've tagged this question as `grep` and `wc`.  You have pretty much answered yourself.

Comment: @larsks Don't even need `wc`.

Comment: True dat. Even *more* already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This writes all lines from file.csv with a "1" to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29):

```
grep "1" file.csv
```

With a pipe you can connect stdout (of grep) and stdin (of wc):

```
grep "1" file.csv | wc -l
```

Comment: What about `grep -c`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Yes, nice idea: `grep -c "1" file.csv`